# ScrollBar not showing if the boundry area is padded

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollbar

[image]

Container is a RelativeLayout, inside there is a ListView with padding. Red area is padded and covered with a frame-like image.

So the problem is, ScrollBar only shows up when the items in the ListViews total height is taller than the **RelativeLayout**, not the padded ListView. Though it scrolls properly when the ListViews height is shorter than the RelativeLayout within the boundries of ListView without showing the scrollBars.

Do you have any idea how I can persuade Android that it is really worth showing the scrollbar?

Edit: I have to add: There is another identical ListView , next to this one in the RelativeLayout. I simplified the code for readibility.

```
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/audiosubtitleview"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomcontrol"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/audiolist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/play_audio_subtitle_bg"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="13dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:visibility="gone" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a padding on your `RelativeLayout` instead of padding on your `ListView`

Comment: Simply can't. This way my frame image is also margined, which is not acceptable.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify; the red Area is your RelativeLayout, while the white is your ListView? If not, could you please post your entire xml file?

Comment: The entire rectangle is RelativeLayout and the inner white rectangle is the ListView with paddings to RelativeLayout. The code I pasted is clearly shows the perpective I guess.

Comment: No it does not. I can't change the margin of the RelativeLayout. It needs to stay in its place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82308/discussion-between-alpaslan-and-hr-frosk).

Comment: Sorry, small mistake; meant padding, not margin. My mistake. It should definitely work now. See updated answer

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, in that case it might help you to add a margin to all of the elements in your listview instead of putting a padding on the listview itself